# Avg() Returns #Error in ReportViewer in c#

Tags: reportviewer2008

I have grouping of columns.
In Group footer i have this expression to give average of scores in that group.

```
=Avg(Fields!Score.Value)
```

When i run the report, Average column shows as #Error.

How can i resolve that.
Im using C# Winforms,VS2008

It shows warning as

```
Warning:The Value expression for the textbox ‘textbox55’ uses a numeric aggregate function on data that is not numeric.  Numeric aggregate functions (Sum, Avg, StDev, Var, StDevP, and VarP) can only aggregate numeric data. (rsAggregateOfNonNumericData)
```

Initially i created table ,by setting Score as char(50). But now i changed in Database,Data type as Decimal  for Score.
And also in reports, Dataset->perfscoretbl->Score->DataType as System.Decimal.

But still it shows as #Error.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this link. It works fine now.[Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/5a28d2aa-4258-4e76-9bca-24e1a3f9b957/sum-gets-error-rsaggregateofnonnumericdata-expression-help)